# Why the OS in VM always blue screen by chance?

Tags: memory, bsod, vmware-player

it always has this error :driver_irql_not_less_or_equal
And as i searched over the internet, I found it might because of the bridged network card problem, it would be OK if i changed to NAT.(but I am not sure)
And after I reduce the memory allocated to the VM, the error didn't occurs till now
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the guest OS, it could be a damaged media you are installing from or some sort of corrupt driver.

If you are talking about the host, it could be that VMware's virtual network drivers are not compatible with your host operating system and causing a problem. You can try upgrading your drivers from the manufacturer (for example [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw)).

Also, just to rule it out, you may want to perform a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org).

If this doesn't help, can you please run [Bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and in your answer, copy and paste the last crash log - again, this is providing the crash happened on your host.

Comment: Yeah, i am talking about the guest OS, it always blue screen unexpectedly, and I can not find the reason, is there any tools to find out the reason quickly?

Comment: Not that I can think of as I haven't really had many problems - What media are you using to install from / where did you get it?

Comment: I just install a windows server 2003, and it always OK, just sometimes it will have blue screen.And I found after i reduce the memory allocated to it, it's OK till now

Comment: I would run a memtest - www.memtest.org just to rule it out.